# Power BI not giving warning

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a csv file with 4gb data, when I put it into Power BI desktop, it works fine, as there is no size limit in Power BI desktop, but if I push it into Power BI service and publish the app then also it does not give any warning or error.

On many platforms it shows csv size limit is 1gb in Power BI service. So I am worried as should I continue using this file or not. As it is working fine now I don't want it to suddenly give me an error one day.

Comment: PowerBi may comrpess the .csv data. So check the .pbix file size. if under 1GB you should be fine. If over 1GB, try do drop useless columns, and/or useless lines.

Comment: @Malo Yes Power BI desktop file size is around 220mb, so you mean to say it is fine to use the csv file of 4gb ?

Comment: I read the limit is about the .pbix, but I cannot test it